# Where can one find the documentation for texlipse parameters?

Tags: acrobat, texlipse

There are parameter placeholders to configure view tools.

Those include "%fullfile", "%line", "%texfile".

Usage examples are DDE Commands:

```
[DocOpen("%fullfile")][FileOpen("%fullfile")]
```

I want to teach my AcrobatViewR11 do do a limited forward search.
I want the document to be opened on the page that corresponds to my cursor position.

The following command opens the document on page 4 (page_index 3)

```
[DocGoTo("%fullfile", 3)]
```

Obviousely i need to replace the fixed parameter 3 with something like "%page".
The following command is ignored and may be wrong:

```
[DocGoTo("%fullfile", "%page")]
```

(EDIT: i have a feeling itis not ignored but ragter %page is treated as 0. Meaning it moves the document to pageindex 0.)

Where can i find the full list of supported texlipse placeholder parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems these are the placeholders that are defined in the source code

```
// the file name variable in the arguments
public static final String FILENAME_PATTERN = "%file";

// the line number variable in the arguments
public static final String LINE_NUMBER_PATTERN = "%line";

// the source file name variable in the arguments
public static final String TEX_FILENAME_PATTERN = "%texfile";

// file name with absolute path
public static final String FILENAME_FULLPATH_PATTERN = "%fullfile";

// the source file name variable in the arguments with absolute path
public static final String TEX_FILENAME_FULLPATH_PATTERN = "%fulltexfile";
```

So perhaps you can play with `%line`?

Source: http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/net.sourceforge.texlipse/ci/master/tree/source/net/sourceforge/texlipse/viewer/ViewerManager.java

And from the documentation

> Using source to output linking Linking source to output means that the
>   viewer is launched viewing the position of output file which
>   corresponds to the position of source files where cursor is currently
>   at. This is commonly referred as forward search. Editors supporting
>   forward search include at least Xdvi in Linux and Yap in Windows.
>
> Configuring forward search happens usually by adding "%line %texfile"
>   to somewhere in the viewer arguments. For example, this is what the
>   Yap viewer has as its default arguments: -1 -s "%line %texfile" %file.
>   When the viewer is launched, %line is replaced with the line number
>   where the cursor is, %texfile is replaced with the name of the file
>   that is currently being edited and %file is replaced with the project
>   output file name.
>
> On Windows it is also possible to use DDE messages to let the viewer
>   know where to open the document. In Acrobat Professional this can be
>   done by adding [MenuitemExecute("GoBack")] to the end of the DDE Open
>   message. See viewer configuration for more about DDE.

http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html

Hopefully this helps,